# Unhandled exception while removing an element from the vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, data-structures

I'm trying to find the intersection of two vectors. I used two loops and if the first loop element is equal to the second loop element, I pushed that element into the vector and then deleted that element. But I keep getting an error "Unhandled exception".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void intersect(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2)
{
    sort(nums1.begin(), nums1.end());
    sort(nums2.begin(), nums2.end());
    vector<int>v;
    if (nums1.size() > nums2.size())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums1.size(); i++)
        {
            int first = nums1[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < nums2.size(); j++)
            {
                if (first == nums2[j])
                {
                    v.push_back(first);
                    nums2.erase(nums2.begin() + i);  //Getting an error here
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; v.size(); i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
}

int main()
{
    vector<int>nums1 = { 1,2,2,1 };
    vector<int>nums2 = { 2,2 };
    intersect(nums1, nums2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a typo, you should've used `j` on that line.

Comment: `nums2.begin() + i` --> `nums2.begin() + j`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but perhaps useful to you if you don't know of it: [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you call the code that's giving you an error, `i` is 2. Since `nums2.begin()` is an iterator the first element, `nums2.begin() + 2` is an iterator to the third element. But `nums2` has no third element. So you are trying to `erase` an element that does not exist.